# How to add subView to another view from third view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, methods

its pretty simple to understand the problem i have.

i have a view called "Menu" - which have few buttons.
i have another view called "Main" - who need to show the view selected by the menu.
and last one i have the view that i want to see in the main view.

i tried to work this out with this code -

```
-(IBAction)opertunity:(id)sender{
OpertunityViewController *temp = [[OpertunityViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OpertunityViewController" bundle:nil];
MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
[main.handlerView addSubview:temp.view];
}
```

but it's not working at all.. i remember i done it many many times in the past but just cant get the answer in my projects... pretty strange /:

UPDATE - 
im trying something else.
i made a method in my main class and i call it from the menu.
but still it dosent work - and i NSLOG the method and its called perfectly.
(when im calling the method from inside the class its working..)

what now ?! i've never had this kind of problem...

Comment: You are not adding the "main" to the screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but i am guessing this is may be yur problem.Did you set the Frame to the Views.

Comment: Take another view and add it to your main.handlerview.So that you came to know know where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add your main view to window or current view. Example:

```
-(IBAction)opertunity:(id)sender{
    OpertunityViewController *temp = [[OpertunityViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OpertunityViewController" bundle:nil];
    MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    [main.handlerView addSubview:temp.view];
    [self.view addSubview:main.handlerView];
}
```

Comment: Allocating new instance of the controller wont help since a new instance is created that dont have any link with the controller that already exist.

Comment: @DimplePanchal I don't know your mean. You mean the new instance don't have any link with the current controller? Sure it don't, but current controller's view has the new instance'view as subview. So, what the problem? Leak or crash?

Comment: See allocating a new instance is not actually the instance that is already present in application window / navigation controller. And even if you call addSubview to a view controller without it loaded in application window, it cant add any subview..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are allocating and creating a new object of `OpertunityViewController`, your view wont be added to that viewcontroller.

For that you need to keep a reference object of `OpertunityViewController` in may be `Menu` and from `Menu` u need to call a method of `OpertunityViewController` that in turn adds subview to your `OpertunityViewController`.

Else you can create a delegate for this functionality.

Hope this helps.

Also if you are using navigation controller, then you can get viewcontroller from stack of navigation controller and then add subview accordingly. Beware you need to get proper viewcontroller from the stack and also be sure that there is no change in the sequence and number of view controllers added at that point of time. This is helpful only when your flow of navigation is fixed or you need to add subview to previous view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This would help i suppose:

```
-(IBAction)opertunity:(id)sender {
   OpertunityViewController *temp = [[OpertunityViewController alloc] init];
   MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
   [main.view addSubview:temp.view];
}
```

Please mark if helpful :)